# Positioning and scaling a background image responsively for a full-screen width div

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, background-image

**Here is what I have:**
An SVG of dimensions 1920*1920 pixels (https://signtalkindia.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/assets/windbg.svg)

**Here's what I need:**

1. I will be using this as a background-image to for a div taking full width of screen.
2. This background-image for the div needs to be responsive.
3. A MUST is having the top of the background visible at all screen sizes i.e. background-image should start at top of the image.
4. Should not repeat.

(The idea is to show the background of the sea which is designed and linked as seen above.)

**Here's what I've tried:**

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

div{
  height: 1000px;
  background: url(https://signtalkindia.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/assets/windbg.svg) bottom top;
  background-size: 150%;
  background-repeat: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

There are a lot of rules mentioned in the "What I need" section that aren't adhered.
Must be simpler than I think it is, but I'd love it if someone could help.
I'm using React, but I don't think that should mattter for this.

Answer (score 0):

a few mistake :

- `bottom` an `top` annihilate each other since it is equal to 100% and 0% for the **vertical axis** .. **horizontal axis is not define** background shorthand is here invalid and won't even show the background-image.
- `background-size : 100% auto` , should be fine enough setting only the horizontal sizing.

demo of what i believe you try to do:

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

div{
  height: 1000px;
  background: url(https://signtalkindia.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/assets/windbg.svg) top center;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```